# Alpine.js table data not refreshing/updating after livewire CRUD or paginate when Collection from livewire updates

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm passing the livewire Collection render to Alpine.js data to output the table along with pagination.

Everything works fine except for the updating of table data when livewire updates. Even the pagination works but the table data is always stuck on the first page.

How do I refresh/update the table based on my CRUD operation and pagination?

```
// LIVEWIRE COUNTRY COMPONENT

public function render()
   {
      $records = Country::with('regions')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(20);
       return view('livewire.admin.countries.datatable', ['records' =>  $records]);
   }

// LIVEWIRE COUNTRY BLADE

<x-datatable.main
   x-data="{
       records: {{ $records->getCollection() }},
       countryID:null,
       regionShow:null
   }"
   x-init="
       console.log(records);
       $watch(' {{ $records->getCollection() }} ',function(value){
       this.records=null;
           this.records=value;
       });
   "
>
<x-datatable.table :dataRecord="$records">
       <table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
           <thead class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
           <tr>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                   Country name
               </th>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center">
                   Continent
               </th>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center">
                   Currency Name (code)
               </th>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center">
                   Phone prefix
               </th>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center">
                   Regions
               </th>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center">
                   Created on
               </th>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-center">
                   Updated on
               </th>
               <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-right pr-8">
                   Action
               </th>
           </tr>
           </thead>


           <template x-for="country in records" :key="country.id">
               <tbody>
               <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                   <td :id="$id(country.name)" x-text="country.name" scope="row"
                       class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap"></td>
                   <td x-text="country.continent" scope="row" class="px-6 py-4 text-center"></td>
                   <td x-text="country.currency_code" scope="row" class="px-6 py-4 text-center"></td>
                   <td x-text="country.phone_prefix" scope="row" class="px-6 py-4 text-center"></td>
                   <td class="px-6 py-4 text-center ">
                       <x-svg.main x-show="regionShow != country.id"
                                   @click.prevent="regionShow = regionShow === country.id ? null :  regionShow = country.id; countryID=country.id"
                                   type="arrow-circle-down"></x-svg.main>
                       <x-svg.main x-show="regionShow === country.id"
                                   @click.prevent="regionShow = regionShow === country.id ? null :  regionShow = country.id; countryID=country.id"
                                   type="arrow-circle-up"></x-svg.main>
                   </td>
                   <td class="px-6 py-4 text-center"><span x-text="country.created_at"></span></td>
                   <td class="px-6 py-4 text-center"><span x-text="country.updated_at"></span></td>
                   <td class="px-8 py-4 text-right space-x-2 overflow-hidden text-right">
                       <x-datatable.update-icon @click="$wire.editButton(country.id)"
                                                @click.prevent="MyModal('country','update',country )"></x-datatable.update-icon>
                       <x-datatable.delete-icon @click="$wire.deleteButton(country.id)"
                                                @click.prevent="MyModal('country','delete',country )"></x-datatable.delete-icon>
                   </td>
               </tr>

               ****** COUNTRY REGIONS ******* 
               <tr x-show="regionShow===country.id" :id="$id('region')"
                   class=" bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">

                   <td colspan="9" class="px-6 py-4 text-center">
                       <template x-for="region in country.regions" :key="region.id">
                           <div class="flex inline-flex">
                               <x-datatable.sub-delete-icon @click="$wire.deleteRegionButton(region.id)">
                                           <span
                                               @click="$wire.editRegionButton(region.id, countryID)"
                                               @click.prevent="MyModal('region','update',region)"
                                               class="flex ml-1 relative z-0  py-1.5 ">
                                               <span x-text="region.name"></span></span>
                                   <x-svg.main type="delete"
                                               @click.prevent="openConfirmationModal=true; formType='region'"
                                               class="flex relative z-50 ml-2 dark:hover:text-red-800"
                                               data-tooltip-target="tooltip-delete"></x-svg.main>
                               </x-datatable.sub-delete-icon>
                           </div>

                           <x-datatable.sub-add-icon @click.prevent="MyModal('region','add')"
                                                     @click="$wire.addRegionButton(data.id)"></x-datatable.sub-add-icon>
                       </template>
                   </td>
               </tr>
               </tbody>
           </template>
       </table>
   </x-datatable.table>
</x-datatable.main>
```